# Proper async/await function

Tags: node.js

I am attempting to run a bot that scrapes Amazon (using amazon-buddy) for certain products (using array of ASINs) and checks the price. If the price is not 0, it should be sending a message on discord. I currently have this set to run every 30 seconds and it's working, but there are times where it seems like each element is not waiting for the previous one to get a response in the forEach loop and my function doesn't seem to be correct (I'm still trying to understand async/await functions properly).

Is there a better way to run this so that each element waits for the previous element to get scraped before moving on to the next one and THEN run the loop again after 30 seconds?

```
(function() {
  var c = 0;
  var timeout = setInterval(function() {
      const checkStock = (async () => {
        config.items.itemGroup.forEach(element => {
          console.log('Checking stock on ' + element)
        try {
          const product_by_asin = await amazonScraper.asin({ asin: element });
          console.log(product_by_asin)
          const price = product_by_asin.result[0].price.current_price
          const symbol = product_by_asin.result[0].price.symbol
          const asin = product_by_asin.result[0].asin
          const title = product_by_asin.result[0].title
          const url = product_by_asin.result[0].url
          const image = product_by_asin.result[0].main_image

          if (price != 0) {
            const inStockResponse = {
              color: 0x008000,
              title: title + ' is in stock!',
              url: url,
              author: {
                name: config.botName,
                icon_url: config.botImg,
                url: config.botUrl
              },
              description: '<@767456705306165298>, click the tite to go purchase!\n\n' +
              'Price: ' + symbol + price,
              thumbnail: {
                url: image
              },
              timestamp: new Date()
              }
        
            message.channel.send({embed: inStockResponse });
            console.log(title + ' (' + asin + ') IS available!')
          } else {
            console.log(title + ' (' + asin + ') IS NOT available!')
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      });
      checkStock()
    });
    console.log('Counter: ' + c)
    c++;
  }, 30000);
})();
```

Comment: The forEach loop won't wait for each iteration to finish before starting another one, is that what you want?

Comment: Yes, I would like each iteration to wait for the previous one to finish before starting the next one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `for...of` loop which can wait for each iteration to finish:

```
async function checkItems(items) {
  // Check all items, wait for each to complete.
  for (const item of items) {
    try {
      const product_by_asin = await amazonScraper.asin({ asin: item });
      console.log(product_by_asin);
      const price = product_by_asin.result[0].price.current_price;
      const symbol = product_by_asin.result[0].price.symbol;
      const asin = product_by_asin.result[0].asin;
      const title = product_by_asin.result[0].title;
      const url = product_by_asin.result[0].url;
      const image = product_by_asin.result[0].main_image;

      if (price != 0) {
        const inStockResponse = {
          color: 0x008000,
          title: title + " is in stock!",
          url: url,
          author: {
            name: config.botName,
            icon_url: config.botImg,
            url: config.botUrl,
          },
          description:
            "<@767456705306165298>, click the tite to go purchase!\n\n" +
            "Price: " +
            symbol +
            price,
          thumbnail: {
            url: image,
          },
          timestamp: new Date(),
        };

        // NOTE: you might want to wait for this too, the error
        // currently isn't being handled like this either.
        message.channel.send({ embed: inStockResponse });
        console.log(title + " (" + asin + ") IS available!");
      } else {
        console.log(title + " (" + asin + ") IS NOT available!");
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }

  // Wait 30s and check again.
  setTimeout(() => checkItems(items), 30000);
}

checkItems(config.items.itemGroup);
```

Comment: That's really helpful - nice to know the difference between `forEach` and `for...of`. This is working great and I'll add another await to help handle errors properly.